# React - HTML5 video element - toggle source depending on aspect ratio?

Tags: reactjs, html5-video

I have an app that needs to serve a 1:1 video OR a 16:9 video depending on viewport aspect ratio.

I can't just show/hide two `<video>` elements with CSS because I'm using `videoRef.current` to handle controls and it's a hat trick to implement that for two refs.

One foreseeable issue I can't wrap my head around would be if someone on desktop had their browser at a square-ish aspect ratio and was seeing the 1:1 video, then hit play and stretched their browser out to make it bigger and the video swapped out during playback. It would seem like there would endless issues trying to manage that behavior.

TLDR; What's the correct way to handle video in React w/ an HTML5 video tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To handle video in HTML you would wrap your video around a source attribute. You can use a ternary operator to change the source depending on screen size or ratio. Something like this

```js
import {useEffect} from 'react'
const vidRef = useRef();
import vid1 from './video1.mp4';
import vid2 from './video2.mp4';
const [width, setWidth] = useState()
cont [height, setWidth] = useState()

useEffect(() => {
    setWidth(window.innerWidth)
    setWidth(window.innerHeight)
}, [])

... (rest of code here)
return (
    <video ref={vidRef} controls>
        { width / height === 1 ? 
            <source src={vid1} type="video/mp4" />
        :
            <source src={vid2} type="video/mp4" />
        }
    </video>
)
```

Where `CONDITION` will be equal to the variable or boolean value that measures your screen size. You can set variables using the `window.innerWidth` or `window.innerHeight` and the condition could be something like `width / height === 1` < Meaning 1:1 ratio. However you want to handle that, it should work!

Comment: Thanks @swellz. That's kind of what I thought. The issue I'm running into now is a bigger can of worms (I think). What if someone on a desktop starts with the 1:1 video, clicks play and then stretches their browser window to make it bigger and it swaps the source mid-playback. It would seem like a major hassle to handle all the possibilities.

Comment: @KirkRoss that's a good question, maybe if you create the width and height variables as state variables that is only initialized in a useEffect hook, you should be okay. As long as those states don't change, the condition will always stay the same. Just be sure to not change those variables and they'll only be initialized on page load or when the user refreshes. I updated my response, hopefully that works!